# Removing blank lines in <pre> with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

How all formats of writing html code below can be issued the same result as in the picture?
[image: Remove Blank Lines]

HTML:

```
<pre><code>The text line 1
The text line 2
The text line 3</code></pre>

<pre><code>The text line 1
The text line 2
The text line 3
</code></pre>

<pre><code>
The text line 1
The text line 2
The text line 3
</code></pre>
```

JS

```
(function() {
    var pre = document.getElementsByTagName('pre'),
        pl = pre.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < pl; i++) {
        pre[i].innerHTML = '<span class="line-number"></span>' + pre[i].innerHTML + '<span class="cl"></span>';
        var num = pre[i].innerHTML.split(/\n/).length;
        for (var j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            var line_num = pre[i].getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
            line_num.innerHTML += '<span>' + (j+1) + '</span>';
        }
    }
})();
```

Code details can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/hidyanaputri/sqq2qkon/1/

Bottom line if the first line or the last row is empty it will not appear numbered. Not a problem if there is a blank line in the middle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couldn't you just trim the content of the `<code>` tags before you number the lines?`

```
$('pre code').text(function(_,t) { return $.trim(t) })
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sqq2qkon/3/)

It the code contains HTML, just return that as the text instead, as `pre` tags will display the HTML as text anyway

```
$('pre code').text(function(_, t) {return $.trim(this.innerHTML)});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/sqq2qkon/4/)

Comment: Yeah like this is what I mean. Thanks a lot @adeneo you've helped me

Comment: @DyanaPutry this will not work if you have html tags inside your `code` tag

Comment: Then how so that this code can work well @IsmailRBOUH. Do you have a better idea? hehehe .. I hope you have a solution

Answer (score 3):

The pre tag preserves both line spaces and breaks, so to get the pre tags all the same format, they will have to have the same stucture eg:

```
<pre><code>The text line 1
The text line 2
The text line 3</code></pre>

<pre><code>The text line 1
The text line 2
The text line 3</code></pre>

<pre><code>The text line 1
The text line 2
The text line 3</code></pre>
```

Your previous html would have line breaks in it:

```
<pre><code>The text line 1
The text line 2
The text line 3</code></pre>

<pre><code>The text line 1
The text line 2
The text line 3<-- line break here
</code></pre>

<pre><code><-- line break here
The text line 1
The text line 2
The text line 3<-- line break here
</code></pre>
```